# Unable to delete a postgreSQL row that has a LEFT JOIN attached

Tags: reactjs, database, postgresql, sql-delete, delete-row

I have created a database using PostgreSQL. I have used LEFT JOIN to join a comments table to a reviews table. The frontend is created using React. I can only delete a review if it has 0 comments, if there are any comments on the review when I try to delete it a 500 internal server error throws. I was sure the LEFT JOIN would delete a review with or without comments, so not sure why this isn't working?

Any suggestions are appreciated, thank you.

https://nc-games-kirsty-richmond.netlify.app

```
// seed.js file

// Create Reviews Table //

const seed = async (data) => {
  const { categoryData, commentData, reviewData, userData } = data;

  await db.query(`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS comments, reviews, users, categories;`);


  await db.query(`
      CREATE TABLE reviews (
        review_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
        designer VARCHAR(55) NOT NULL,
        owner VARCHAR(180) REFERENCES users(username),
        review_img_url VARCHAR(500) DEFAULT 
            'https://images.pexels.com/photos/163064/play-stone-network-networked-interactive-163064.jpeg',
        review_body VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
        category VARCHAR(75) REFERENCES categories(slug),
        created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        votes INT DEFAULT 0
        );
      `);

  // Create Comments Table //

  await db.query(`
      CREATE TABLE comments (
        comment_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        body VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
        votes INT DEFAULT 0,
        author VARCHAR(75) REFERENCES users(username) NOT NULL,
        review_id INT REFERENCES reviews(review_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        created_at  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      );
      `);
```

```
// review-models.js

exports.selectReviewById = async (review_id) => {
  const review = await db.query(
    `SELECT reviews.*, COUNT(comment_id)
    AS comment_count
    FROM reviews
    LEFT JOIN comments
    ON comments.review_id = reviews.review_id
    WHERE reviews.review_id = $1
    GROUP BY reviews.review_id;`,
    [review_id]
  );
  return review.rows[0];
};

exports.removeReview = async (review_id) => {
  removeComment();

  const review = await db.query(
    `DELETE FROM reviews
      WHERE review_id = $1;`,
    [review_id]
  );
  return review.rows[0];
};
```

```
Errors in console:

DELETE http://be-nc-games-app.herokuapp.com/api/reviews/114 500 (Internal Server Error)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:210
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:15
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:58
request @ Axios.js:112
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:136
wrap @ bind.js:9
deleteReview @ api.js:116
handleDelete @ ReviewCard.jsx:55
onClick @ ReviewCard.jsx:77
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js:66:1)
createError @ createError.js:16
settle @ settle.js:17
onloadend @ xhr.js:66
Promise.then (async)
handleDelete @ ReviewCard.jsx:55
onClick @ ReviewCard.jsx:77
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:3945
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:3994
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4056
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:4070
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:8243
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:8275
processDispatchQueue @ react-dom.development.js:8288
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ react-dom.development.js:8299
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:8508
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22396
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3745
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:8507
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6005
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5924
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:468
runWithPriority$1 @ react-dom.development.js:11276
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:22413
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:3756
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5889
```

Comment: If the table has `ON DELETE CASCADE` in the FK constraint definition, then there should be no problem when deleting the parent row. Please include the specific database error. An "HTTP 500" can be related to other non-database problem.

Comment: Have you looked at the Postgres log to see if is showing an error?

Answer (score 0):

If you can delete only records that are not commented.

```
delete from reviews where id in (
    select a.id  
    from reviews rv 
    left join comments cm on rv.id = cm.rev_id 
    where cm.id is null
)
```

Left join will be select all records. But if reviews are not commented these records showed as `NULL`. So adding the `CM.ID IS NULL` condition will filter only no comments records. After then using the subquery we can delete needed records.